# Change the way my pc puts the imported images and videos according to time they were taken

Tags: import

Change my import settings from "put photos according to date taken" to "put photos according to same month"?

Actually, when I was backing up my mobile phone's data, it asked me whether to make folders according to the month the photo was taken(ie. to keep the photos taken in same month together) or to make folders for the media according to DATE TAKEN (ie. put media taken on same day together). So I selected the second option, but after being backed up, it seems like a proper mess. Please help me to change the setting to "keep media according to month taken".

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. All we have to do is that go to 'START button' in windows and then select 'PHOTOS', there you will find an option to import, from there, it would ask you to select the device from which you want to import media and then it would ask you how to keep the media, ie. accordint to month they were taken or according to date they were taken.